# best way to allow search engine to crawl site

Tags: seo, search-engine, web-crawler

Thanks for reading my question. I am building a site that will be listing products from each manufacturer. I'm planning to structure the URL as following variations:

www.mysite.com/manufacturer_name/product_name/product_id

www.mysite.com/product_name/product_id

www.mysite.com/manufacturer_name

There are millions of products and I want all the major search engine to crawl them. What is the best way to go about doing that?

Would simply submitting site to all the search engines be enough? I would assume if I submit the manufacturer page which lists out all the manufacturer name as links the search engine will click on each links and click on all the products displayed within each manufacturer  links (I will have paging for products) so the search engine can keep crawling the site for more products within each manufacturer until it runs out of the page number.

Would that be sufficient to list out each product on the every search engine? or is there a new and better way to do this? May be there are new SEO tricks that I'm not aware of. I am hoping if you can point me to the right direction.

I've previously used robot.txt to tell search engines which pages to crawl and that seemed to work fine.

Thanks,
bad_at_coding

Comment: Do I list all the prodcuts in sitemap.xml? or simply a URL or two to lead them to the manufacturer page?

Answer (score 1):

Submit an XML sitemap. The easiest way to do this is to link to it in your robots.txt file.

Sample robots.txt file:

```
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap_location.xml
```

See [Submitting Sitemaps](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183669) for more on this topic from Google